# Deep Net with keras for image segmentation

Tags: keras, image-segmentation

I am pretty new to deep learning; I want to train a network on image patches of size (256, 256, 3) to predict three labels of pixel-wise segmentation. As a start I want to provide one convolutional layer:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2d(32, 16, 16, input_shape=(3, 256, 256))
```

The model output so far is an image with 32 channels. Now, I want to add a dense layer which merges all of these 32 channels into three channels, each one predicting the probability of a class for one pixel.

How can I do that?

Comment: What is a format of your y's? What shape do they have?

Comment: (256,256); every pixel gets a label assignment

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method to merge your 32 channels back to 3 would be to add another convolution, this time with three filters (I arbitrarily set the filter sizes to be 1x1):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2d(32, 16, 16, input_shape=(3, 256, 256))
model.add(Convolution2d(3, 1, 1))
```

And then finally add an activation function for segmentation

```
model.add(Activation("tanh"))
```

Or you could add it all at once if you want to with **activation** parameter (arbitrarily chosen to be tanh)

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2d(32, 16, 16, input_shape=(3, 256, 256))
model.add(Convolution2d(3, 1, 1,activation="tanh"))
```

https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/

Answer (score 1):

You have to use flatten between the convolution layers and the dense layer:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2d(32, 16, 16, input_shape=(3, 256, 256))
# Do not forget to add an activation layer after your convolution layer, so here.

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid")) # whatever activation you want.
```